# Lambda use in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe
type are:

```
FiscalYear      int64
GL             object
GLID            int64
GL_Debit      float64
GL_Credit     float64
month          object
diffDebit     float64
diffCredit    float64
diffval       float64
```

I try to modify a float column (diffvalue) to multiply it on a condition
My code is:

```
df['diffval'] =  df.apply(lambda x: x['diffval']*-1 if x['GL'].str[0] in ['4','0'] else x['diffval'])
```

Im trying to do this but I have an error:

> KeyError: ('GL', 'occurred at index FiscalYear')

dataframe sample :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
thanks

```
FiscalYear  GL  GLID    GL_Debit    GL_Credit   month   diffDebit   diffCredit  diffval
2020    1001 Banque:RBC 06621-1006014 (Salle Privée)    70  19386,69    0   2020-01-01  19386,69    0   19386,69
2020    1001 Banque:RBC 06621-1006014 (Salle Privée)    70  0   5074,84 2020-02-01  -19386,69   5074,84 -24461,53
2020    1002 Banque:Desjardins 0282527 (Traiteurs)  71  2758,45 0   2020-01-01  2758,45 0   2758,45
2020    1002 Banque:Desjardins 0282527 (Traiteurs)  71  2765,64 0   2020-02-01  7,19    0   7,19
2020    1003 Banque:Desjardins 0282857 (ED) 54  36725,91    0   2020-01-01  36725,91    0   36725,91
2020    1003 Banque:Desjardins 0282857 (ED) 54  117149,35   0   2020-02-01  80423,44    0   80423,44
2020    1004 Banque:RBC 05261-1020403   231 30282,34    0   2020-01-01  30282,34    0   30282,34
2020    1004 Banque:RBC 05261-1020403   231 2277,34 0   2020-02-01  -28005  0   -28005
2020    1061 Dépôt Stripe à recevoir:Stripe - Salle Privée  219 7208,32 0   2020-01-01  7208,32 0   7208,32
2020    1061 Dépôt Stripe à recevoir:Stripe - Salle Privée  219 6015,4  0   2020-02-01  -1192,92    0   -1192,92
2020    1062 Dépôt Stripe à recevoir:Stripe - Traiteurs.Co  220 1643,28 0   2020-01-01  1643,28 0   1643,28
2020    1062 Dépôt Stripe à recevoir:Stripe - Traiteurs.Co  220 2678,28 0   2020-02-01  1035    0   1035
2020    1099 Fonds non déposés  8   1200    0   2020-01-01  1200    0   1200
2020    1099 Fonds non déposés  8   0   0   2020-02-01  -1200   0   -1200
2020    1100 Compte clients (C/C)   74  65665,57    0   2020-01-01  65665,57    0   65665,57
2020    1100 Compte clients (C/C)   74  94235,09    0   2020-02-01  28569,52    0   28569,52
2020    1300 Actif du stock 68  0   0   2020-01-01  0   0   0
2020    1300 Actif du stock 68  0   0   2020-02-01  0   0   0
```

Comment: Whatever `x` is, it doesn't have a `'GL'` key. I wonder how we are supposed to find the problem when we don't know the contents of the DataFrame - at least a **minimal** example of it - [mcve]

Comment: can you provide some data sample and the expected output for that

Comment: Which axis are you applying the function to?? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=axis#pandas-dataframe-apply

Comment: Sorry Guys, Answers:

Comment: Dataframe has 9 columns: FiscalYear, GL, GLID, GL_Debit, GL_Credit, month, diffDebit, DiffCredit, diffVal

Comment: axis to be used  is rows

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Hi wwii, I add axis= 1 at then end of may Code: df['diffval'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['diffval'] * -1 if x['GL'].str[0] in ['4', '0'] else x['diffval'], axis=1) but error is now :AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 0'). thanks to help ?

Comment: can you show us the result of `df.columns`?

Comment: result : Index(['FiscalYear', 'GL', 'GLID', 'GL_Debit', 'GL_Credit', 'month',
       'diffDebit', 'diffCredit', 'diffval'],
      dtype='object')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing the dataframe along columns. So when using lambda, specify the axis as 1:

```
df['diffval'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['diffval'] * -1 if x['GL'].str[0] in ['4', '0'] else x['diffval'], axis=1)
```

Just noticed your comment,

You do not need to specify .str as it is already a string.

```
df['diffval'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['diffval'] * -1 if x['GL'][0] in ['4', '0'] else x['diffval'], axis=1)
```

If it is required to convert to string, you may use,

```
df['diffval'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['diffval'] * -1 if str(x['GL'])[0] in ['4', '0'] else x['diffval'], axis=1)
```

Does this work, or am I missing something?

Comment: Cheers! if you find it suitable, you may accept the answer to close the topic.

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, you don't need to use the `apply` command (which is slow). You can solve this using `loc`. 
 
Select rows where **GL** starts with '4' or '0' and then multiply to -1 the **diffval** column

```
mask = df['GL'].str[0].isin(['4','0'])

df.loc[mask, 'diffval'] = df.loc[mask, 'diffval'] * -1
```